# How do I dynamically obtain the set of classes implemented for a sealed trait using object.getClass (as opposed to using a type parameter)?

Tags: scala, reflection, traits, sealed

**Summary:**
Using an object which contains both a `sealed trait` and all of its implementers, how can obtain the set of the class names of all the `sealed trait` implementers using the the containing object's `getClass` method (as opposed to using a type parameter)?


**Details:**
I am currently using Scala 2.11.2 and am attempting to obtain the set of descendants from a `sealed trait`. I have seen [Travis Brown's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081069/501113). However, it uses a type parameter of `Root: TypeTag`. I need to be able to seed the scan by dynamically discovering the `Symbol` at runtime via an `object` instance's `getClass` method.

Consider this example class:

```
object SealedTest {
  sealed trait T
  case object A extends T
  case object B extends T
}
```

My goal is to have a function outside of `object SealedTest` which looks like this:

```
def getSealedTraitImplementers(clazz: Class[_]): Set[String]
```

Calling `getSealedTraitImplementers(SealedTest.T.getClass)` would return `Set(A, B)`. And I do get that obtaining the class for `SealedTest.T` is a bit more involved than this over simplified example (actual full details are in the `val sealedDescendantsViaClassInstance` below).


Here's what I have tried thus far:

Using Travis's code as a starting point, I created this function:

```
def inspect(symbol: Symbol): Option[Set[Symbol]] = {
  val internal = symbol.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#Symbol]
  if (internal.isSealed)
    Some(internal.sealedDescendants.map(_.asInstanceOf[Symbol]) - symbol)
  else None
}
```

I then take his original primary entry point and defined it like this:

```
def sealedDescendants[Root: TypeTag]: Option[Set[Symbol]] = {
  val symbol = typeOf[Root].typeSymbol
  inspect(symbol)
}
```

And this succeeds in returning `Set(object A, object B)` when called like this:

```
val resultSealedDescendants =
  sealedDescendants[SealedTest.T] match {
    case Some(set) => set.toString
    case None => "<empty>"
  }
println(s"sealedDescendants[SealedTest.T]=${resultSealedDescendants}")
```

While it isn't a `Set[String]`, it's trivial to get there with `resultSealedDescendants.map(_.toString.stripPrefix("object ")`.


Now, for what I haven't been able to get to work. I define this function to obtain the `Symbol` from the existing runtime class instance of `SealedTest.T`:

```
def sealedDescendantsViaClassInstance: Option[Set[Symbol]] = {
  val classSealedTestT = Class.forName(SealedTest.getClass.getName + "T")
  val runtimeMirrorTemp = runtimeMirror(classSealedTestT.getClassLoader)
  val classSymbol = runtimeMirrorTemp.staticClass(classSealedTestT.getName)

  //???missing transform of ClassSymbol to Symbol???

  inspect(classSymbol)
}
```

And this fails in returning `<empty>` when called like this:

```
val resultSealedDescendantsViaClassInstance =
  sealedDescendantsViaClassInstance match {
    case Some(set) => set.toString
    case None => "<empty>"
  }
println(s"sealedDescendantsViaClassInstance=$resultSealedDescendantsViaClassInstance")
```

I am clearly obtaining a `Symbol` (`ClassSymbol` to be more precise). However, the `inspect` function is not returning a `Set`. So, I think there is still some transformation I need to do on `classSymbol` before calling `inspect`. What is the missing transform?

---

**UPDATE:**
After spending hours trying to close this gap, I gave up and modified the original object to add an (ugly) explicit type class. This is very much not the desired solution. The object now looks like this:

```
object SealedTest {
  sealed trait T
  case object A extends T
  case object B extends T
  def typeTagT: TypeTag[_] = typeTag[SealedTest.T]
}
```

I still have the need for the original requirement to be able to start at the `getClass` for `T`. So, if you have any clue how I can start from there to dynamically constitute a type class which can produce the needed Symbol for `sealed trait T`, I would really appreciate it. I will post an answer if I end up figuring it out.