# Getting case object instances which derive from a sealed parent in Scala

Tags: scala

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078366/can-i-get-a-compile-time-list-of-all-of-the-case-objects-which-derive-from-a-sea) is essentially my question, but the accepted answer stops at returning their symbols rather than the case objects themselves.

In theory, this should be easy:

```
def getCaseObjects(enumType: Type) = {
    val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    enumType.typeSymbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses map { subclass =>
        val enumObjMirror = m.reflectClass(subclass.asClass.toType.typeSymbol.asClass)
        enumObjMirror.reflectConstructor(subclass.asClass.toType.decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod)()
    }
}
```

And this works!

...Except that they are entirely new instances compared to the ones contained in their `Parent` sealed trait; hooray, I've busted the "case objects are singleton" assumption!

I could override `equals` and `hashCode` in my `Parent` sealed trait and be done with it, but I'd prefer a way to get *those particular* case objects rather than ones that happen to look like them. Is this possible? I'm on 2.11 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use the `sealedDescendants` method in the post you reference, I believe you should be able to get the underlying `object`s like:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe => ru }
val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val descendants = sealedDescendants[Parent] getOrElse Set.empty

val objects = descendants.map({ desc =>
  val mod = m.staticModule(desc.asClass.name.decoded)
  m.reflectModule(mod).instance
})
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much.