# Advice on Case Classes/Objects/Matching

Tags: scala

I am trying to model (in my Scala application) a list of options presented in my web page and am scratching my head coming up with a solution for mapping a `String` value posted from the client to it's corresponding object in the backend.

eg. Let's say it is a list of `Animals` and the user can choose 1 which gets posted to the backend.

```
Animals
   Polar Bear
   Rabbit
   Great White Shark
```

When a request comes in, I want to convert the ***Great White Shark*** `String` to an `Animal` but not sure on how best to match the 
`String` to the appropriate type in the backend.

So far I have this.

```
sealed abstract class Animal(val name: String)

case object GreatWhite extends Animal("Great White Shark")
case object PolarBear extends Animal("Polar Bear")
```

Which allows me to do this to match the String from the UI to it's corresponding case object in my Scala application.

```
def matcher(animal: String) = animal match {
    case GreatWhite.name => GreatWhite
    case PolarBear.name => PolarBear
}
```

**Problem**

If the List of Animal's grows long however, this matcher is going to be very cumbersome since I need to have a `case` expression for every `Animal`.

I would much appreciate any experienced Scala guys giving me a pointer on a more elegant solution.

Comment: Which framework are you using for the Client - Backend communication?

Comment: The interface if a RESTful API so it is a POST with a JSON body.

Comment: Perhaps with play/spray?

Comment: @Yuval, Ye I am using Play for backend at present (might look to use Spray instead since I believe it is a bit more lightweight if you don't need the Scala templating etc). The frontend is an Ember app.

Comment: Minor note: Spray has been inactive for sometime, [Akka HTTP](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/http/) module supercedes it - I think it's being developed by the original author(s) of Spray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's looks like what you need is simply have a hash table of String to Animal.
Such approach gives you ability to get result in constant time O(1) even with extensivly growing list.

```
val mapping = Map[String, Animal]("Rabbit" -> Rabbit, "Polar Bear" -> PolarBear /* ... */ )

// matcher
mapping.get(animal)
```

UPD.
Some useful comments below.

```
  sealed abstract class Animal(val name: String)

  case object GreatWhite extends Animal("Great White Shark")
  case object PolarBear extends Animal("Polar Bear")

  val mapping: Map[String, Animal] = Seq(GreatWhite, PolarBear).map(x => x.name -> x).toMap
  mapping
```

Comment: To avoid typos, maybe `Rabbit.name -> Rabbit, PolarBear.name -> PolarBear` instead of replicated string literals.

Comment: Is there a way to do `getAllSealedClassObjects.map( _.name -> name)` ?

Comment: Thanks - I like that, and thanks for the O notation note. I may go with this but let me see what other solutions come in before I mark it as answer.

Comment: If there is no getAllObjects then maybe `val mapping = Seq(Rabbit, PolarBear).map( _.name -> name)`

Comment: @Thilo looks like yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078366/can-i-get-a-compile-time-list-of-all-of-the-case-objects-which-derive-from-a-sea

Comment: @Thilo, can you help me out understanding your latter suggestion please?
`val mapping = Seq(Rabbit, PolarBear).map( _.name -> name)` This generates a new Map with the mapping for the `name` to -> the Object right? I'm currently getting not recognized for the last `name` though so I guess the bit of you example that I need to finish I dont quite understand.

Comment: Seq(GreatWhite, PolarBear).map(x => x.name -> x)

Comment: @rumoku, thanks for that but I don't get how the resulting List of Sequences is useful since to match I need to do something like this right? `mapping.find(_ == (animal, GreatWhite))` ie. I need to explicitly state the Type of Animal I'm looking for. No doubt it's cause I'm a Scala newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Enums? If they are usable for you, Enums have a `.withName` method http://yefremov.net/blog/scala-enum-by-name/